# Delete Button not working properly (DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, netbeans, aptana

Ok here is what I was trying to do... Create a delete button along with edit by using DOM while creating a paragraph. But delete button always seems to be deleting first paragraph instead of deleting the corresponding paragraph.. here's my code:

`Javascript:`

```
 function writePara()
 {
    var comment = document.getElementById("usrinput").value;
    var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    newParagraph.textContent = comment;
    document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(newParagraph);

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    var Btext=document.createTextNode("EDIT");
    button.appendChild(Btext);
    document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(button);

    button.onclick = 
    (
        function() 
        {
    var edit = prompt("Type to edit", "");
    newParagraph.innerHTML = edit;
        }
    );
    var button2 = document.createElement("button");
    var Btext2=document.createTextNode("DELETE");
    button2.appendChild(Btext2);
    document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(button2);
    button2.onclick = 
    (
        function ()
        {

    var items = document.querySelectorAll("#updateDiv p");
        if (items.length) 
    {
        var child = items[0];
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    }
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
    button2.parentNode.removeChild(button2);
        }


    );
    addBr();
  }
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: I think it has to do something with this bit:


      `{
        var child = items[0];
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
     }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a reference to the new paragraph in the `writePara` function and you already used it once in the edit handler, so why don't you use it again in the delete handler?

```
button2.onclick = 
(
    function ()
    {
        newParagraph.parentNode.removeChild(newParagraph);
        button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
        button2.parentNode.removeChild(button2);
    }
);
```

Here's how it works: http://jsbin.com/nohud/1/edit. Write something in the input and click outside of it a few times to generate some paragraphs.

**Edit**: The code above utilizes closures. It is important to understand that each time `writePara` is called, the `newParagraph` variable points to a new DOM element and each click event handler defined in the same function has access to that specific element in the `newParagraph` variable. So whenever the edit/delete handlers are called `newParagraph` is the element with which the associated buttons have been created when `writePara` has been called.

Here's some code that explains that clearer that I do:

```
function init() {
    var name = "Mozilla"; // name is a local variable created by init
    function displayName() { // displayName() is the inner function, a closure
        alert (name); // displayName() uses variable declared in the parent function    
    }
    displayName();    
}
init();
```

It is taken from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures. More also here: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

From there on `newParagraph.parentNode` is the container containing the new paragraph, so `newParagraph.parentNode.removeChild(newParagraph)` just removes that specific element from its container.

Comment: @simich..... Works!!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Can you add some comments please so that i can understand it better?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are always giving index[0] so that its deleting first paragraph as shown below

```
var child = items[0];
```

it should be

```
newParagraph.parentNode.removeChild(newParagraph);
```

Comment: I know! 
How do I get around that? So that it deletes the corresponding paragraph instead first paragraph? @Neel

Comment: so is it `var child = this.parentNode.removeChild(this);` ?

@Neel

Comment: Yep... @Neel Thanks man It works as above also answer by simich is a lot better!